# Create Excel from Parent excel

Tags: python, excel

Below creates a file and then fills in the excel. I would like to create an excel file with a condition based on a single column and redeposit the excel with a prefix of the column name.
So return only where columnX = i and create and save excel file i1_CCBHC_MONTHLY_CLAIMS.XLSX 
i2_CCBHC_MONTHLY_CLAIMS.XLSX

I have the build of the large "parent" excel file.

```
    filename = 'CCBHC_Monthly_Claims.xlsx'    
if os.path.isfile(filename):
    wb = xw.Book(filename)
    ws = wb.sheets['CCBHC_DATA']
    ws.range('A1').options(index=False).value = df_ora
    wb = xw.Book(filename)
    xw.apps[0].quit()
else:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter')  
    *df_ora.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='CCBHC_DATA',index=False)
    wb = xw.Book(filename)
    ws = wb.sheets['CCBHC_DATA']
    ws.range('A1').options(in*dex=False).value = df_ora
    wb = xw.Book(filename)
    xw.apps[0].quit()
```

Comment: What are you trying with this line `ws.range('A1').options(index=False).value = df_ora`?

Comment: Refilling a specific tab with the dataframe. Frankly I would prefer that the df_ora be conditioned and an excel created each time. Currently the df_ora is the parent dataframe I am in need of subsequent dataframes from a single one